# Convert String to Date not working

Tags: android, simpledateformat

```
String date="12/20/20102";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");           
             Date today;
            try {
                today = df.parse(date.trim());
              Log.e("Error", "Correct");
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Error", "InCorrect");
            }
```

I am not able to get this corrected. I always get this converted and if I give an incorrect date string also it not catching in the exception.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string input is :

```
String date="12/20/20102";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Two mistakes:

1. String date = "12/20/**20122**"; // it shoud be "12/20/**2012**"
2. Your String input is in **MM/dd/yyyy** format and you trying to parse in **dd/MM/yyyy** format. Change your string input format (20/12/2012) OR change formatter to (MM/dd/yyyy).

**EDIT**

Here is sample code for validating user input date in **dd/MM/yyyy** format.

```
String str = txt.getText().toString();

            try{
            String tmp[] = str.split("/");
            int day = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);

                if(!(day > 31) && !(month > 12) && (tmp[2].length() == 4) )
                {
                    // Verified date....
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter date in correct format. (dd/MM/yyy)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Note: Leap year and February month logic is not implemented.

Full validation with all conditions available here.
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/

And don't forget to accept this if it helps you.

Thanks...

Comment: "12/20/20102"-This is not a static string .It can be entered by the user on the text-field.Then, how can i validate this as wrong(user must type "dd/MM/yyyy" format)?

Answer (score 2):

`String date="12/2/2012"` should be `String date="12/02/2012"`. There should be leading zeros.

ex.

```
int month = 3;
int dayOfMonth = 4;
int year = 2012;

String date = String.format("%02d",dayOfMonth)+"/"
             + String.format("%02d",month)+"/" 
             + year;
```

Comment: Even if I put String date="12/20/20102" it converts and not catching the exception.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)   <--- check this out and look for the parse method. It says ParseException is raised only if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed.

Comment: then what will do for date validation?

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have 
    String date="12/20/20102";

is this correct or the correct one must be

```
String date="12/20/2012";
```

Comment: I know the correct string. I need to find or validate this as wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try this way it works

```
 String s_date="12/1/2006";
 Date date = null ; 
 DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 date = (Date)formatter.parse(s_date);
```

Comment: I need to validate the user entered date string

Comment: @Arun try validation as on http://sanjaal.com/java/672/java-regular-expressions/date-format-validation-mmddyy-and-ddmmyy-in-java-using-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you are checking whether the date entered by user is write or wrong.then use the below method to check.

```
private boolean convertStringToDate(String date){
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");           
        Date today = null;
        try {
            today = df.parse(date.trim());
            Log.e("Error", "Correct");
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error", "InCorrect");
            return false;
        }       
        return true;//if every thing is write
    }
```

and from your code you can use it as below

```
boolean isValidDate = convertStringToDate("12/20/20102");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Want To Validate User Entered Date.

Your Code is.

```
String date="12/20/20102";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");           
         Date today;
        try {
            today = df.parse(date.trim());
          Log.e("Error", "Correct");
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error", "InCorrect");
        }
```

I know this will not caught any exception.But if you entered **20102** this not sets year as **2012**.
So after above code check condition..

```
       if(!(df.format(today).equals(date))){
                 Log.e("Error", "InCorrect Date");
           }
```